# C move node in linked

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I wrote a code that get from the user the name of the node to move and the index to move to. and my code desn't work like I wanted, all the nodes after the node to move are disconnected. Someone know how to fix that?? (my approach to this is to move the "frame" (node) one step forward every time). the struct is in the end

```
FrameNode* MovePos(FrameNode* list, int number_of_nodes)
{
    char name[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    int index = 0, pos = 1;
    bool flage = false;
    printf("Enter the name of the frame\n");
    fgets(name, STR_LEN, stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
    flage = searchInList(list, name);
    if (!flage)
    {
        return list;
    }
    printf("Enter the new index in the movie you wish to place the frame\n");
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &index);
        getchar();
        if (index > number_of_nodes)
        {
            printf("please enter number between 1-%d\n", number_of_nodes);
        }
    } while (index > number_of_nodes);
    FrameNode* p = list;
    FrameNode* prev = p;
    FrameNode* save = NULL;
    while (strcmp(p->frame->name, name))
    {
        prev = p;
        p = p->next;
        pos++;
    }
    for (int i = pos; i < index; i++)
    {
        prev->next = p->next;
        save = p->next;
        save->next = p;
    }
    p->next = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

```
typedef struct Frame
{
    char* name;
    unsigned int    duration;
    char* path;
} Frame;

// Link (node) struct
typedef struct FrameNode
{
    Frame* frame;
    struct FrameNode* next;
} FrameNode;
```

Comment: Recommendation: Draw on paper how you would have to switch the pointers. You shouldn't have to set all those next pointers in the loop, instead you should just adjust the `next` pointer of the predecessor of the node to be removed to the latter's successor, then advance n positions, finally adjust the successor of the node to be moved to current node's successor and currents node successor to the node to be moved.

Comment: Side note: What happens if the user enters a negative index? You might rather want to scan to `unsigned int`, then you don't have this problem. Otherwise you'll need to check for index being < 0 as well. Additionally you don't have appropriate behaviour defined if the index is smaller than the node's current position.

Comment: Recommendation:  Use separate functions for **1)** getting the user input,**2)**  for locating the node, and **3)** for the actual move/insertion.